# Single leg stand exercise

Tags: legs, rehabilitation, feet, functional-strength, balance

Am I right in thinking that this exercise can be used to strengthen your feet aswell as your hips?

In the past I was given it by a physio due to my problems with flat feet / plantar fasciitis. The physio said to contract the arch of my foot as I was doing it in order to strengthen it and help rebuild my arches.

More recently, I was given this same exercise to strengthen my weak hips (including glute medius). And this physio (a different one to last time) said for me to keep my foot flat on the floor and focus on using my hip muscles to keep my balance.

I'm wondering, is it okay to use this exercise to strengthen my feet and hips simultaneously? Or should I perhaps take turns, and do sets focussing on my feet and then sets focusing on my hips?

Comment: With your history of problems with flat feet/plantar fasciitis, you should probably direct this question to your therapist.

Comment: If I am correct in understanding this exercise is "just" standing on one leg with no motion other than stabilizing with your foot and hip: It's probably okay (unless your injured or have an active medical issue in which case definitely see a doctor) to just do 2 sets : one focusing on the foot, and then one focusing on the hip. Regardless of where your focus is, both areas will be at least a little bit active. Maybe decrease the length of the hold a bit if you're going to do it twice and are worried about too much volume.